# Can't figure out why javascript isn't working in my php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Found the code for this GPA calc on github and haven't been able to get it working. The look appears correctly, but it will not calculate the GPA and the add/delete row buttons do not work. Here is the link to the files on github. https://github.com/xandroxygen/GPACalc

```
<?php

    $GRADELIST = array(
        "A+"=>"4.0",
        "A"=>"4.0",
        "A-"=>"3.7",
        "B+"=>"3.4",
        "B"=>"3.0",
        "B-"=>"2.7",
        "C+"=>"2.4",
        "C"=>"2.0",
        "C-+"=>"1.7",
        "D+"=>"1.4",
        "D"=>"1.0",
        "D-"=>"0.7",
        "E"=>"0.0",
    );

    // check input
    function validate_input($data)
    {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }

    // convert grades to points per hour
    // returns -1 if grade not recognized
    function grade_convert($g)
    {   
        global $GRADELIST;
        $p = -1.0;
        if (array_key_exists($g,$GRADELIST))
        {
            $p = $GRADELIST[$g];
        }
        return $p;
    }

    // import JSON string
    $json_data=array();
    $raw_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    parse_str($raw_data,$json_data);

    // parse form input
    $name = "";
    $points =  $hours = $gpa = 0.0;

    $name = validate_input($json_data["name"]);
    $points = validate_input($json_data["points"]);
    $hours = validate_input($json_data["hours"]);
    $classes = $json_data[0]["classes"];

    // add classes in
    foreach($classes as $c)
    {
        $c_pts_per_hour = grade_convert($c[grade]);
        if ($c_pts_per_hour > -1) // else, invalid grade (lowercase, P, IE, W, etc)
        {   
            // find grade points, multiply by class hours, add to total hours 
            $c_pts = $c_pts_per_hour * $c[hours]; 
            $points += $c_pts;
            $hours += $c[hours];
        }
    }

    // calculate and output GPA
        if (is_numeric($hours) && ($hours > 0))
        {
            $gpa = $points / $hours;
        }
    echo $name . ", your GPA is " . number_format($gpa,2) . ", and you have earned " . $hours . " total hours.";
?>
```

Split

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
    .error {color: #FF0000;}
    .input-group-btn {padding-bottom: 10px;}
    h5 {width: 50%;}
</style>
<head>
    <title>GPA Calculator</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Functions for processing and calculating gpa -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Sandbox_4_App/script.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>GPA Calculator</h1>
        <p>Use your current points and hours, class enrollment, and projected grades to calculate your GPA!</p>
        <h5>I built this the first week of my current job to teach myself basic principles of web design, like client-side scripting, PHP form handling, and AJAX calls.</h5>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Current GPA container -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Calculate GPA</div>
        <div class="panel-body">

            <!-- Form for Name/Points/Hours -->
            <form role="form" action="">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Name: <span id="nameREQ"><small>(required)</small></span><span id="nameERR" class="error">This field is required!</span></label> 
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="curr_points">Current Points: 
                                <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Points and hours are found on your transcript"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="curr_points" name="curr_points">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="curr_hours">Current Hours: 
                                <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Points and hours are found on your transcript"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="curr_hours" name="curr_hours"><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!-- Table for Class/Grade/Hours -->
                <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                <thead>
                    <tr >
                        <th class="text-center">
                            #
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            Class
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            Grade
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            Hours
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="classes_list">
                    <tr id='addr0'>
                        <td>
                        1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name='class0'  placeholder='Class' class="class form-control"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name='grade0' placeholder='Grade' class="grade form-control"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name='hours0' placeholder='Hours' class="hours form-control"/>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>

            <!-- Add/Delete/Submit Buttons -->
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                   <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Row</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Row</a>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" name="submit_form">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>       
    <div id="showGPA" class="alert alert-success">
        <a  class="close" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
        <p><span id="result"></span></p>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Split

```
// --- main jQuery function ---
$(function() {
    $(".alert.alert-success").hide();
    $(".error").hide();

    // --- submit a form ---

    $(".btn.btn-primary").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".error").hide();
        $("#nameREQ").show();

        // validate name, gather input
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        if (name == "")
        {
            $("#nameREQ").hide();
            $(".error").show();
            return false;
        }
        var points = $("input#curr_points").val();
        var hours = $("input#curr_hours").val();

        // process form
        var formData = "name=" + name + "&points=" + points + "&hours=" + hours;
        $.post("getGPA.php", formData, function(data) {
                $("#showGPA").show();
                $("#result").text(data);
            });
    });

    // --- close the alert box and ready for new submit ---

    $(".close").click(function() {
        $(".alert.alert-success").hide();
    });

    // --- enable tooltips
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
    });
});
```

Here is my updated code after making some changes. The calculating gpa part still isn't working, and the add/delete rows isn't working because I believe that section of code is missing. I am not sure how to get that add/delete row code working.

Comment: any error you are getting?

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR It does not give me any errors, the bootstrap is working correctly, but any functions will not work. Add/Delete row will not work, and when I try to calculate GPA it just says 0.0. I thought that I was calling the javascript file correctly, but the functions appear to not be working. I also am not sure how to call the php file from the index.php file.

Comment: @BradleyNewman i see two errors - first $raw_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $json_data = json_decode($raw_data, true); -> $raw_data isn't json.
Sec - validate_input($json_data[0]["person_name"]); -> you sent name not person_name

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR actually in the script.js file dreamweaver is telling me that there is an error on line 3 column 5 for "missing use strict statement. There is another error on line 15 column 20 that says "expected === instead of ==", but idk if this is causing my issues as it seems like weird warnings.

Comment: @Matx132 So I should change the lines to $data = decode($raw_data, true); and validate_input($json_data[0]["name"]; ?

Comment: @BradleyNewman you send as POST then use $_POST like this -> 
    $name = validate_input($_POST["name"]);
    $points = validate_input($_POST["points"]);
    $hours = validate_input($_POST["hours"]);
---- then i get  your GPA is 0.94, and you have earned 342 total hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your javascript, I don't see anything that's binding an action to your add/delete row buttons. That's probably why they don't do anything.

Your code for submitting the form data to the PHP script is fine, although it would be better to just send an object instead of building the request body yourself, because you're currently not escaping any of the values. So if the name contains an `&` or `/` or any of a number of other characters, the request body will be invalid:

```
var formData = {
    "name": name,
    "points": points,
    "hours": hours
};

// just send an object, let jQuery deal with escaping it
$.post("getGPA.php", formData, function(data) {
    $("#showGPA").show();
    $("#result").text(data);
});
```

On the PHP side of things, you're accessing the raw input. That's completely unnecessary. You're performing a regular POST request and sending proper values, so you can simply get the values from `$_POST`. You are most definitely NOT sending JSON to the server, so calling `json_decode()` doesn't make sense.

```
// import JSON string
// $raw_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
// $json_data = json_decode($raw_data, true);
// remove those lines, they don't do anything useful.

// parse form input
$name = "";
$points =  $hours = $gpa = 0.0;

$name = validate_input($_POST["name"]);
// note: you're sending "name" to the server, not "person_name"

$points = validate_input($_POST["points"]);
$hours = validate_input($_POST["hours"]);
$classes = $_POST["classes"];
```

I don't know where `"classes"` is coming from, because you're not sending any classes to the server.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, and it still isn't working. I believe it may be because I haven't called the PHP code in the original file? Should I just paste the php somewhere in the body of the index.php file?

Comment: No, that shouldn't be necessary. What is your browser's console telling you? Are you getting javascript errors?

Comment: I am using dreamweaver to try to update this to a website. The only errors dreamweaver is telling me about are located in the script.js file and it says missing use strict statement on line 3 and expected === and instead saw == on line 15

Comment: This is what the browser console says, 

Console
What's New




Filter



index.php:1 Mixed Content: The page at  was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure favicon . This content should also be served over HTTPS.
index.php:1 Mixed Content: The page at  was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure favicon . This content should also be served over HTTPS. I removed the links for security reasons

Comment: I just forked your code and tweaked it until it works, turns out I was dead wrong about the `data.responseText` thing. If you set that back to just `$("#result").text(data);` it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

i think u must parse ur post data as,try this

```
// import JSON string
    $json_data=array();
    $raw_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    parse_str($raw_data,$json_data);

    // parse form input
    $name = "";
    $points =  $hours = $gpa = 0.0;

    $name = validate_input($json_data["name"]);
    $points = validate_input($json_data["points"]);
    $hours = validate_input($json_data["hours"]);
    $classes = $json_data[0]["classes"];
```

Comment: This actually worked more than other solutions, but it only got the name field to work. After doing your suggested changes the other fields are still not being calculated. Is this a javascript error?

Comment: @BradleyNewman have u connect ur index,script and php file together,bcaz i'm not seeing it on ur github repository files, they are unconnected to each other. and also i could not get what is stand for $classes = $json_data[0]["classes"] if u describe i could help u with more easily, and also update ur github file with new one if possible

Comment: I have edited the original post to reflect the current files.